# Check for a duplicate within powerpivot on the fly

Tags: powerpivot, powerbi, excel-2016

In my organization various sales personnel could be part of many sales transactions, and I have a table below that shows for each sales personnel the amount revenue they were part of. However, depending on how a user is using the table, the pivot may double/triple count revenue data.

As an example when a user filter on SalesManager1, there will be a duplicate as both SalesPersonnel 1 and 3 have sold ProductA. However, When a filter on just SalesPersonnel1, there's no double count. similarly, when a user selects SalesManager4 although he has 2 Sales personnel reporting to him/her they were part of distinct sales transactions thus there's no duplicate.

I want to create a measure which flags when there's a potential duplicate in the view users are looking at. However, I cannot go back and change how the data model was built. Is there a way to do this all within the data model? I know  I can probably create a pivot table share the filter/slicer, and then count # of sales personnel for the accounts and products, but I'm hoping for more of sophisticated solution...
would appreciate any help/support you can provide!

thank you

```
SalesManager  SalesPersonnel   Acccount   Product  Revenue
SalesManager1 SalesPersonnel1 Acccount_A Product_A 100000
SalesManager1 SalesPersonnel1 Acccount_B Product_C 100000
SalesManager1 SalesPersonnel3 Acccount_A Product_A 100000
SalesManager2 SalesPersonnel3 Acccount_B Product_C 100000
SalesManager1 SalesPersonnel2 Acccount_B Product_C 100000
SalesManager1 SalesPersonnel2 Acccount_B Product_C 100000
SalesManager4 SalesPersonnel4 Acccount_B Product_A 100000
SalesManager4 SalesPersonnel4 Acccount_A Product_D 100000
SalesManager4 SalesPersonnel5 Acccount_A Product_B 100000
SalesManager4 SalesPersonnel5 Acccount_A Product_A 100000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question, but here is what I did. I've taken the hint from the above poster, and arranged it to my own need.

here is what I did: 
I added a new column that would combine Account, Product, and Revenue

```
ConsldforDupeCheck:=Acccount&Product&Revenue
```

and then created a measure

```
DoubleCountCheck = if(CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT([ConsldforDupeCheck]))=COUNTROWS(Table),"","*PossibleDoubleCountError*")
```

this allowed to have a measure that checks the duplicate on the fly.
Thanks Bob for the hint!!

Comment: Well you got a solution, hope my efforts helped :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a simple measure to count salespersons

```
  CountSalesPersonnel:=IF( COUNTA( Table1[SalesPerson] ) > 1, "Oops, "")
```

Comment: If I go with this approach, and if a user selects SalesManager4, wouldn't it show up as "Oops" even though there's no duplicate?

Comment: You are right, but SalesManager4 does have duplicates for Product A, so you would need to include Product in the pivot and maybe try
Duplicates:=IF(DISTINCTCOUNT( Table1[SalesPerson] ) > 1, "Oops, "")

Comment: Product A isn't duplicate though, because it was sold to Account B. When Sales Manager 4 is chosen, there is no duplicate. Sales Personnel4 sold Product A to AccountB and Product D to Account A. SalesPersonnel5 sold Product B and Product A to Account A.